# Lumen returns error after executed "composer update command"

Tags: lumen

After executed composer updated lumen retuns arror.

```
message": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request::getPayload(): Return value must be of type Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\InputBag, Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ParameterBag returned",
"exception": "TypeError",
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\octilus\\talc_claim\\talc064-api-be\\prod-web\\talc064-api-be\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Request.php",
"line": 1517,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\octilus\\talc_claim\\talc064-api-be\\prod-web\\talc064-api-be\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php",
        "line": 84,
        "function": "getPayload",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request",
        "type": "->"
    },
```

Here is the composer.json code

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.269",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",
        "illuminate/redis": "^9.52",
        "irazasyed/larasupport": "^1.1",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^9.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.15",
        "monolog/monolog": "^2.9",
        "predis/predis": "^2.1",
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^8.0",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^3.4",
        "setasign/fpdf": "^1.8",
        "setasign/fpdi": "^2.3",
        "shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue": "^3.0",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
```

In web.php route is like this

`$router->post('get-uuid', 'V1\UserAgentController@getUUID');`

This route returns error

Comment: Try to reinstall dependencies - rm -rf vendor && composer install

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading laravel/framework (v10.16.0 => v10.16.1) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

please follow below steps

```
Step 1 : delete vendor folder and composer.lock file

Step 2:add 
"symfony/http-foundation": "6.2"  in composer.json file

Step 3 : execute composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error was due to this upgrade: Upgrading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.2.0 => v2.3.0) (Lumen (9.1.6) (Laravel Components ^9.36.3))

Solution: simply run composer update again: Upgrading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.3.0 => v2.3.1)

in symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.3.1) the issue has been fixed.